# Process to release module and plugin for Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-template, joomla1.6

I have created separate plugin and module for Joomla 1.5 and Joomla 1.6

I wanted to release these plugin and module.

Before releasing, wanted to know that are there any process and registration do we need to do for Joomla plugin and module?

Thanks,

Pravin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add your extension to [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org) you have to [register](http://extensions.joomla.org/component/user/register?option=com_alpharegistration&Itemid=&view=register) and your addons should be compliant with listing rules over JED

Quoted from JED :

> Any person or company is welcome to
>   submit their extensions, tools or
>   libraries for inclusion in the Joomla!
>   Extensions Directory. There are some
>   basic rules that all extensions must
>   comply with to qualify for inclusion
>   in the Directory. Failure to comply
>   may result in removal from the
>   Directory.
>
> By submitting a listing to the Joomla!
>   Extensions Directory, you agree to be
>   bound by these rules.
>
> D2. Extensions, tools and libraries
>
> 1. Extensions must comply with Joomla! trademark policies.
> 2. An extension's XML file should contain the copyright and license tag
>      and state it is licensed under the
>      GPL.
> 3. The file headers of an extension should contain a copyright notice and
>      a notice that the file and extension
>      is distributed under the terms of the
>      GPL.
> 4. A copy of the GPL needs to be included with the extension package.
>      The copy of the GPL does not need to
>      be installed with the extension.
> 5. Extensions must have basic functionality. Basic functionality is
>      to be determined at the discretion of
>      the Joomla! Extensions Directory team
>      and Open Source Matters.
> 6. All extensions must be installable on the Joomla! platform. The only
>      exception to this rule are the
>      applications in the 'Tools' category.
> 7. Extensions which alter any code must do so through the standard
>      Joomla! install and uninstall process.
>      Uninstalling should revert any changes
>      made to the original code.
> 8. Extensions may not 'call home' to function. Extensions are allowed to
>      'call home' to do version checks and
>      other 'call homes' will be evaluated
>      on a case by case basis. Acceptance of
>      a method and/or function is at the
>      sole discretion of the Joomla!
>      Extensions Directory team and Open
>      Source Matters.
> 9. Extensions may not be commercially encrypted.
> 10. Extensions may only solicit votes and/or reviews in the manner defined
>       below.
> 11. Extensions which are forks must comply with the forking policy listed
>       below.

That's it!